# How to compare the response of multiple GET requests after they all complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, nodeunit

I want to make sure the each time I make a specific get request I get the same result for a specific array in the body called `spells`. (SIDE NOTE: I will also write a different test to make sure another part of the body `active_spell` is random/different at least some of the time). I've written the following code but can't seem to get into the 'data' or 'end' events.

So why am I not getting into the 'data' and 'end' events?

And really the main question, is there a more proper or efficient way to reach my main objective, which is to ensure the spellbooks returns the same each time?

NOTE: I Don't mind looking at libraries to help with this, but I am looking for a way to do this without needing to add more.

```
var config = require('./../config');

//Setup client with automatic tests on each response 
var api = require('nodeunit-httpclient').create({
    host: config.api.host,
    port: config.api.port,
    path: '/api', //Base URL for requests
    status: 200, //Test each response is OK (can override later)
    headers: { //Test that each response must have these headers (can override later)
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
});

exports.spellbook_get = {
 'ensure spells are always the same': function(test) {
    //2 default tests in the client plus the one below
    test.expect(3);

    var urls = ['/spellbook', '/spellbook', '/spellbook', '/spellbook'];
    var completed_requests = 0;

    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        var responses = [];

        api.get(test, url, function(res) {

            res.on('data', function(chunk){
                console.log('YAY!-DATA');
                responses.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on('end', function(){
                console.log('YAY!-END');
                if (completed_requests++ == urls.length - 1) {
                    // All requests are completed
                    var uniques = [],
                        hashes = {};

                    for (var i=0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                        var hash = JSON.stringify(responses[i].spells);
                        if (!(hash in hashes)) {
                            hashes[hash] = true;
                            uniques.push(responses[i].spells);
                        }
                    }
                    //test that there is only 1 unique array
                    test.equal(uniques.length, 1, 'All spells responses must match');
                    test.done();
                }
            });
        });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You seem to be throwing the chunks of all responses that you get into the same array. Aren't those forming strings that you would need concatenate per request and parse before using them?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:promise]? Do you intend to use them? Have you tried?

Comment: Please, remove the `promise` tag -- it confuses people. `apt.get` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: I removed the promise tag. I thought that might be an option but I don't really understand promises or how to use them.